# How can i hide and display elements automatically?

Tags: php, theme-development, customization, themes

I have at the end of my blog page an element that shows / lists the next articles from page 2.

If there is no second page , this element shows nothing.

I would like to hide the element automatically, as long when there is no second page.

Once there is a second page, the item should be displayed automatically.

Does anyone know how I can implement something like that?

here is a screenshot of this element when the blog have two sites: [image]

and here, when an second page does not exist: [image]

You'll see, this looks not nice when an second page does not exist.

I have implemented this function with the following code:

```
                <?php if ( is_home() && !is_paged() ) {
              $post_num = get_option('posts_per_page'); ?>
              <div class="next-content">
                <div class="page-header"><h3 class="article">Further articles<a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>page/2/" title="Zur Seite 2">on page 2</a>:</h3></div>
                <ul>
                <?php query_posts('showposts='.$post_num.'&offset='.$post_num);
                if (have_posts()) : ?><?php while (have_posts()) : the_post();  ?>
                  <li><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
                <?php endwhile; ?><?php endif; ?><?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
                </ul>
              </div>
            <?php } ?>
```

I hope you can help me! :>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use 2 properties of the global `WP_Query`: `max_num_pages` and `paged`.

After that avoid using `query_posts` for the new query use a new instance of `WP_Query` or `get_posts`.

```
global $wp_query;
if ($wp_query->max_num_pages > 1 && $wp_query->get('paged') < $wp_query->max_num_pages ) {
  $next_page = (int)$wp_query->get('paged') + 1;
  ?>
  <div class="next-content">
    <div class="page-header"><h3 class="article">Weiter <a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>page/<?php echo $next_page; ?>/" title="Zur Seite <?php echo $next_page; ?>">auf Seite <?php echo $next_page; ?></a> mit:</h3></div>
    <?php
    $post_num = $wp_query->get('posts_per_page') ? : get_option('posts_per_page');
    $next_posts = get_posts('posts_per_page=' . $post_num . '&paged=' . $next_page);
    if ( ! empty($next_posts) ) {
    echo '<ul>';
    foreach( $next_posts as $next_post) {
    ?>
    <li><a href="<?php echo get_permalink($next_post) ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php echo get_the_title($next_post); ?></a></li>
    <?php
    }
    echo '</ul>';
    }
    ?>
  </div>
  <?php
}
```

Comment: **hazelnut**, my solution is very similar to the one posted by @s_ha_dum. He beat me by 2 minutes... but I had written all answer when got notified of his answer so I've posted it. The only difference is that my solution works also for other pages than 2: on 2nd page it preview the 3rd page posts and so on. If you don't need this feature mark s_ha_dum answer as accepted.

Comment: i have tried it and put the code into the have_posts block and it do nothing. :< I have put it after the ":" in `<?php if ( ! have_posts() ) : ?>`

Comment: @hazelnut if you mean the `<?php if ( ! have_posts() ) : ?>` block in your code, you don't need it at all. My code is the only thing you need. Just use it after closing the main loop.

Comment: i don't get it. I get an White Page of Death. Look at my index.php http://pastebin.com/QsNq9Lq7 have i forgot something?

Comment: Ah, i got it! Sry i was a little bit tired and I'm a newbie on PHP. :-) Thanks for you solution!

Answer (score 1):

Just move all of the markup into the `have_posts` block.

```
if ( is_home() && !is_paged() ) {
  $post_num = get_option('posts_per_page'); 
  $next = new WP_Query('posts_per_page='.$post_num.'&offset='.$post_num); 
  if ($next->have_posts()) {
    while ($next->have_posts()) { 
      $next->the_post(); ?>
      <div class="next-content">
        <div class="page-header"><h3 class="article">Further articles<a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>page/2/" title="Zur Seite 2">on page 2</a>:</h3></div>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
        </ul>
      </div><?php 
    }
  }
  wp_reset_postdata();
}
```

Notes:

1. You should not be using `query_posts` so I changed it.
2. `showposts` is deprecated and has been for a very long time now, so
   I changed it.
3. "Alternative" control structure syntax it nothing but confusing,
   hard to read, and prone to error, so I changed it.
4. Since you haven't clobbered the `wp_query` global with `query_posts`
   you don't have to reset the whole query. `wp_reset_postdata` is good
   enough.